# RecyclerView in tab not showing any items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

While creating the title similar questions were suggested to me.
I took a look at 'em all but I didn't find the answer I was looking for so here I go.

I have a Fragment "Planning" which will hold different fragments.
It will have a TabLayout with three tabs using the same ListFragment named "PlanningListItemFragment".

It will hold a recyclerview which will add items using the "PlanningItemFragment" and the adapter "RecyclerViewAdapter".

My app runs smoothly and gives me no errors at all.
Unfortunately, no items are visible in any of my tabs.
I don't understand where the issue is and I hope you can help me.
Here is the code:

Fragment Planning:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planning,
                container, false);
        final Button chooseDate = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.chooseDate);

        // Code for setting the date with calendar
        chooseDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {

                                        DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                                        datePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "date picker");

                                      }
                                      });

        //code for the tablayout

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.planning_tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        FragmentManager cfManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(cfManager);

        // add Fragment Here

        adapter.addFragment(new PlanningListItemFragment(),"Breakfast");
        adapter.addFragment(new PlanningListItemFragment(),"Lunch");
        adapter.addFragment(new PlanningListItemFragment(),"Dinner");
        // set Icons to tabs

        // tablayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.X1):
        // tablayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.X2):
        // tablayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.X3):

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // remove shadow from the action bar
        // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionbar();
        // actionBar.setElevation(0);


        return view;
    }
```

As you can see it has 3 tabs.

PlanningListItemFragment:

```
public class PlanningListItemFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    private List<PlanningItemFragment> lstPlanningItem;

    public PlanningListItemFragment() {

    }

    @Nullable
    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planning_list, container, false);
        mrecyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.RCview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(),lstPlanningItem);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        Log.d("debugMode", "The onCreateView method has been launched");
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO: 22/05/2018 Implement the call to get the meal picture from the database

        lstPlanningItem = new ArrayList<>();
        lstPlanningItem.add(new PlanningItemFragment("Menu A", "keywords", R.drawable.ic_nav_ic_meal));




    }
}
```

log.d shows me that the OnCreateView method is being called correctly.

FragmentPlanningList.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RCview">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

PlanningItemFragment:

```
public class PlanningItemFragment {

    private String Name;
    private String Keywords;
    private int Photo;


    public PlanningItemFragment(String name, String keywords, int photo) {
        Name = name;
        Keywords = keywords;
        Photo = photo;
    }

    // getter

    public String getName(){
        return Name;
    }

    public String getKeywords(){
        return Keywords;
    }

    public int getPhoto() {
        return Photo;
    }
```

Item_Planning xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/img_meal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:id="@+id/item_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Key words"
            android:id="@+id/keywords"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

Context mContext ;
List<PlanningItemFragment> mData;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<PlanningItemFragment> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v ;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_planning,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_keywords.setText(mData.get(position).getKeywords());
        holder.img_photo.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_name;
        private TextView tv_keywords;
        private ImageView img_photo;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            tv_keywords =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.keywords);
            img_photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_meal);

        }
    }



}
```

Planning XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Fragments.planning">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseDate"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:hint="Tap to select a date!"
        android:textColorHint="@color/blue"

        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateGiven"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/planning_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/blue"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/blue"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager">


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</LinearLayout>
```

Most of the issues I found on this site had to do with the getItemCount() returning 0. But this is not the case here.

I hope you can give me some insights since my logcat is not displaying any errors I am lost...
Needless to say I am pretty new at this stuff and still have a lot to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: can we see your fragment_planning.xml?

Comment: I added the xml, thanks

Comment: The inner `LinearLayoutCompat` in the "Planning XML" layout has no `orientation` specified, so it's `horizontal`. Since the `TabLayout`'s `layout_width` is `match_parent`, the `ViewPager` is being pushed out the side, off-screen. You could specify a `vertical` orientation on that `LinearLayoutCompat`, or you could just remove it, since the root `LinearLayout` is already `vertical`, and the `LinearLayoutCompat` isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I dont have enough credits to comment)

Can you log the size of list lstPlanningItem before setting adapter?
See if its zero.
Try uncommenting @Override for onCreateView and move your List initialisation and updation part to onCreateView(),

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planning_list, container, false);
    lstPlanningItem = new ArrayList<>();

    mrecyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.RCview);
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),lstPlanningItem);
    mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    lstPlanningItem.add(new PlanningItemFragment("Menu A", "keywords", R.drawable.ic_nav_ic_meal));
    Log.wtf("size_of_my_list", Integer.toString(lstPlanningItem.size()));
    recyclerAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
    Log.d("debugMode", "The onCreateView method has been launched");
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
When I do that, I do get a Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.meat_timealpha10.Fragments.RecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount

So it would seem it is '0' but how come? I thought I did everything right...

Comment: I have edited my code. Try it . I have changes getContext() to getActivity() . I dont think that matters. Also I have tried to log after list initialization and updation(which means list cannot be null).See what it logs for size of list.

Comment: Thank you again.
I have implemented the changes and it confirms that the list is not null anymore:

E/size_of_my_list: 1

But still no items are showing :(

Comment: Do you get any error now? Simply no items are being displayed?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. Just no items displayed. If it helps I can maybe upload a picture and send you a link. Again, I appreciate the help you've given me so far!

Comment: No problem. Upload picture and post it

Comment: Uploaded the image here (nevemind the ugly colors) : https://ibb.co/hP6m6T

Comment: It must be something with your layouts. Adapter looks fine. Activity is fine too.

Comment: Try changing layout_width of recyclerView to match_parent

Comment: Still nothing.Looks like it will remain a mystery :(

Answer (score 0):

@jonamar please try to update this line,

FYI I have also faced similar issue a long time back and as far I remember I have update below code and everything works.

```
mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

with

> ```
> LinearLayoutManager llm= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
> mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(llm);
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it did not help.
Still no error and still no items in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

As Mike M said, this was the answer:

The inner LinearLayoutCompat in the "Planning XML" layout has no orientation specified, so it's horizontal. Since the TabLayout's layout_width is match_parent, the ViewPager is being pushed out the side, off-screen. You could specify a vertical orientation on that LinearLayoutCompat, or you could just remove it, since the root LinearLayout is already vertical, and the LinearLayoutCompat isn't really necessary

Thank you so much!